# LOAD DATA not available; fgetcsv times out; alternatives?

Tags: mysql, csv, timeout, load, fgetcsv

I have a site where a CSV of racehorse data is to be uploaded once a week.  The CSV contains the details of about 19,000 racehorses currently registered in the UK and is about 1.3MB in size, on average.  I have a script that processes that csv and either updates the horse if it exists and the ratings data has changed, or adds it if it doesn't exist.  If a horse is unchanged, it skips to the next one.  The script works, as it was running on the host I use as a test.  It took 5 or 6 minutes to run (less than ideal, I know), but it worked.

However, we're now testing on the staging version of the client's host, and it's running for 15 minutes and then returning a 504 timeout.  We've tweaked htaccess and php.ini settings as much as we're able ... no joy.

The host is in a shared environment, so they tell me that MySQL's LOAD DATA is unavailable to us.

What other alternative approaches would you try?  Or is there a way of splitting the CSV into chunks and running a process on each one in turn, for example?